# Map array elements into properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a 3rd party service that returns an array of size four arrays.

The array is structured like

```
[
 [Time, Min, Max, Average],
 [Time, Min, Max, Average],
 etc
]
```

Is there a way to implicitly define an interface such that I can deal with properties when referring to this data?

something like

```
interface ApiResult {
  ItemArray: Item[]
}

interface Item {
  Time: string,
  Min: string,
  Max: string,
  Average: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define an interface because the array holds elements of primitive type `string` (Came to know about the type from your example interface) and not an object. It is simply calling the array as an array of type string. For the outer array which is holding all these arrays, we can call it as an array that holds arrays of type string, that is:

```
var data: Array<Array<string>> = [
 ["Time", "Min", "Max", "Average"],
]
```

If your array is holding an object with those four properties, then you can specify the type like:

```
interface Item {
  Time: string,
  Min: string,
  Max: string,
  Average: string
}

var data: Array<Array<Item>> = [
 [{"Time": "Time", "Min": "Min", "Max": "Max", "Average": "Average"}],
]
```